# Kudu not supported .net core 3.1: can not autodeploy my .Net core 3.1 function from bitbucket

Tags: azure, bitbucket, kudu

I've used the bitbucket to deploy my function app to azure: when I check in on master in Bitbucket, my code gets deployed to Azure.

That worked great, but now I upgraded my function app from .net core 2.2 to 3.1 and...

Now I've got this exception:

```
Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
Handling function App deployment with dotnet.exe.
D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk\2.2.109\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(137,5): error NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 3.1.  Either target .NET Core 2.2 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 3.1. [D:\home\site\repository\xxxxxx\xxxxxx\xxxxxx.csproj]
D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk\2.2.109\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(137,5): error NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 3.1.  Either target .NET Core 2.2 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 3.1. [D:\home\site\repository\xxxxxx\UnitTest\UnitTest.csproj]
Failed exitCode=1, command=dotnet restore "D:\home\site\repository\xxxxxx\xxxxxx.sln"
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
\r\nD:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\85.11226.4297\bin\Scripts\starter.cmd "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
```

So it says it doesn't support .net core 3.1

That is a clear error because I just updated it.

But I can't figure out what is giving me the error. I can't imagine it's Azure complaining, because they do support .net core 3.1 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions). I also can't imagine that the sources are built-in Bitbucket (are they?) and that Bitbucket doesn't support .net core 3.1?

EDIT
I found some info on the one word 'Kudu'. Seems that it is on Azure, and responsible for deployments from (amongst others) GIT to Azure. So now I wonder why Kudu doesn't support .net core 3.1

Edit 2:
My listed frameworks:

```
D:\home>dotnet --list-runtimes
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.14 [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.15 [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.8 [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.14 [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.15 [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.8 [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.0.1 [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.0.2 [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.0 [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.1 [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.0.16 [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.1.13 [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.9 [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.14 [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.8 [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.0.2 [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.1 [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

EDIT 3:

Can it be that this host.json is wrong?

```
{
    "version": "2.0"
}
```

Didn't read that it had to be changed, but maybe?

Comment: I also changed the 'FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION' setting from ~2 to ~3

Comment: Try running `dotnet --list-runtimes` via Kudu (https://yourwebsite.scm.azurewebsites.net). Maybe 3.1 is not installed yet. You could also try using a Linux app service. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60130669/cant-create-new-net-core-3-1-web-app-in-azure-under-windows-operating-system/60131205#60131205

Comment: Thanks, I've added the runtimes in the question. 3.1 is present. Can it be that 3.1 is long out, but not available in Azure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the reason while writing another comment. From what I can see, you are pushing your sources to the AppService and let Kudu build the application. This does not work because while the 3.1 **runtime** is installed, the 3.1 **SDK** is not.

You will also see that if you run `dotnet --list-sdks`. You need to build your application before pushing it to Kudu, or wait until the 3.1 SDK is installed on the windows systems. You can also still try to use a Linux App Service.

https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/217

> The SDK deployment will happen once the runtime is globally available.

After more than three months, runtime deployment is still not complete. So I expect the SDK deployment to take a bit more time.

Comment: You are right, the SDK is not present. After all these years building apps in VS didn't know you had to have the SDK to build apps. So I have 2 options: wait for the availability or use a Linux app service. Do I need to create an entire new function app for that?

Comment: Happens to the best ;-) You need a Linux app service plan and a new function app

Comment: Linux app service plan can't be in the same resource group as the windows plan.

Comment: Think I'll wait then.